# FabricJS adding new line in text object

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

As far as I am aware it is not possible to add padding to textBackgroundColor in FabricJS (padding exists but it has no affect on textBackgroundColor), so I am trying to hack the look of the text to give the impression there is padding.

I am doing this by automatically adding whitespace at the end of each line within the text object. It's not elegant, but it comes close.

However I am stuck on 1 problem and my code has become a little messy.

Now adding a new line (hitting return) does not work as expected.

The cursors seems to appear behind the character it should and have to hit return 2 times to get to a new line, by which time an empty line has been added.

What's gone wrong, how can I get this back on track?

I thought to solve the empty line bug it would make sense to only add the white space if the line contained 1 or more characters, but I couldn't achieve this.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cj604tf7/1/)

JS

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas');
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject(str1);

var objects = canvas.getObjects();
var concatstr = '';
var res;
var str;
var str1;
var abcd;
canvas.on('text:changed', function() {
  var concatstr = '';
  var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var txtsa = jQuery.trim(activeObject.text);
  values = txtsa.split('\n');

  jQuery.each(values, function(index, val) {
    jQuery.trim(val);
    concatstr += " " + val + " " + "\\n";
  });
  var temp = concatstr.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
  var final = temp.replace(/\\n/g, "\n");

  activeObject.setText(final);
});

var text1 = new fabric.IText(' Text ', {
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  textBackgroundColor: '#000',
  fontSize: 30,
  lineHeight: 0.9,
  fill: 'white',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica Nue, Helvetica, Sans-Serif, Arial, Trebuchet MS',
});

canvas.add(text1);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52903599/text-background-color-padding-in-fabric-js-canvas) where the is a potential answer for padding and margin on text objects.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think adding text to your text to obtain a  padding is a good solution.

Even if your question is about adding spaces and keypress, i m showing you an alternative way to add the padding to background color.

```js
fabric.Object.prototype._renderBackground = function(ctx) {
      if (!this.backgroundColor) {
        return;
      }
      var dim = this._getNonTransformedDimensions();
      ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;

      ctx.fillRect(
        -dim.x / 2 - 10,
        -dim.y / 2 - 10,
        dim.x + 20,
        dim.y + 20
      );
      // if there is background color no other shadows
      // should be casted
      this._removeShadow(ctx);
    };

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mycanvas');
var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject(str1);

var objects = canvas.getObjects();
var concatstr = '';
var res;
var str;
var str1;
var abcd;

var text1 = new fabric.IText(' Text ', {
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  backgroundColor: '#000',
  fontSize: 30,
  lineHeight: 0.9,
  fill: 'white',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica Nue, Helvetica, Sans-Serif, Arial, Trebuchet MS',
});

canvas.add(text1);
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

as you see overriding the default backgroundColor function is very easy.
While is hard to add options for everyone in the library, prototype changes let you obtain your custom behaviour with ease.

Comment: this is a route I tried - although not as elegant as yours - but I am looking to achieve a background color only behind the text characters (like in my fiddle) similar to how textBackgroundColor works, but with padding. This solution adds a rectangle behind the entire text object using backgroundColor.