# Retrieving quadrant name (origin) when moving an object - Canvas, Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Thank you for the time taken to read, and potentially help. So I've started experimenting with canvas and fabric.js - no experience what so ever.

I've hit a stumbling block, and that's getting the origin, or rather the location of a moving object. It appears that originX, originY is always the same value, regardless of where an object is moved to.

For a visual indicator, I've created an image:

[image]

What I don't understand is why originX, and originY is always left, and top? I assume this is the location of the control for offset?

I'm hoping their is some built in canvas/fabric methods, If not could any of you kind folk point me in the right direction on trying to output the correct origins of when an object is dropped?

A small snippet of just trying to log the output when moving an object:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', e => {
     
      console.log("moving target, X: " + e.target.originX);
      console.log("moving target, Y: " + e.target.originY);

      console.log("moving active obj, X: " + canvas.getActiveObject().originX);
      console.log("moving active obj, Y: " + canvas.getActiveObject().originY);

      const coords = e.target.calcCoords();
      const trans = e.target.calcTransformMatrix();

      console.log(coords);
      console.log(trans);
      console.log(e.target.getOrigin());
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you modify the origin of a fabricjs object, querying it's `.originX` and `.originY` won't ever return
anything else than **left** and **top** respectively simply because these properties do **not** refer to it's on-screen position.

An object's origin refers to it's own coordinate space and it's meaning becomes more obvious if you think about
a transformation like scale applied to an actual object.

Have a look at the following example. The origin of the square to the left is at center/center while it's top/left for the square to the right.

```js
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c1");
let context = document.getElementById("c1").getContext("2d");
let rectA = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: "blue",
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  originX: "center",
  originY: "center"
});
canvas.add(rectA);

let rectB = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: "blue",
  left: 150,
  top: 50,
  originX: "left",
  originY: "top"
});

canvas.add(rectB);

let scale = 1;
let a = 0;

function updateCanvas() {
  rectA.scale(scale);
  rectB.scale(scale);
  scale = 1 + Math.sin(a);
  a += 0.1;
  canvas.renderAll();

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(50, 50, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 2;
  context.strokeStyle = 'red';
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(150, 50, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fill();
  context.stroke();
}

let interval = setInterval(updateCanvas, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/451/fabric.min.js" integrity="sha512-qeu8RcLnpzoRnEotT3r1CxB17JtHrBqlfSTOm4MQzb7efBdkcL03t343gyRmI6OTUW6iI+hShiysszISQ/IahA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<canvas id="c1" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

If you want to know which quadrant of the canvas is occupied by your object, you have to manually
calculate it based on your object's coordinates.

Here's another example - try dragging the circle around.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c1', {
  backgroundColor: "#cccccc"
});
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 30,
  fill: '#f55',
  top: 100,
  left: 100
}));

canvas.on('object:moving', e => {
  if (e.target.left < canvas.width / 2) {
    if (e.target.top < canvas.height / 2) {
      console.log("TopLeft");
    } else {
      console.log("BottomLeft");
    }
  } else {
    if (e.target.top < canvas.height / 2) {
      console.log("TopRight");
    } else {
      console.log("BottomRight");
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/451/fabric.min.js" integrity="sha512-qeu8RcLnpzoRnEotT3r1CxB17JtHrBqlfSTOm4MQzb7efBdkcL03t343gyRmI6OTUW6iI+hShiysszISQ/IahA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<canvas id="c1" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Good Morning @obscure, Thank you very much for the time taken to write a detailed answer. This certainly does solidify some of my observations, and unknowns. Stay Safe,